# combine partitions when already split up with Windows XP installed on one

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, partitioning

I'd like to consolidate two partitions on my laptop.  I have Windows running on one partition, and I have another partition that I store data on.  These partitions are on the same hard drive.  Is this possible without reformatting the hard drive and making a single partition?  If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use tools like partition magic or Arconis disk director to merge two partitions together.

Comment: Make sure to take a backup of your data on a separate device. XP installs can be flaky.

Comment: Partition Magic > Tools > Merge Partitions ... then choose drive with Windows first, and secondary partition second ... it'll ask you to reboot for the merge to take place .. allow the blue screen of Windows XP to finish after the reboot for the merge to finish